# UIImageView won't display chosen image from UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

My imageView doesn't display the picture I choose with the UIImagePicker.

Here's all the code for it:

```
@IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any) {
    if !didShowCamera {
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        } else {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
    print(image)
    self.jobImage.image = takenImage
    self.takenImage = image
    didShowCamera = true
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like a constraint issue

Answer (score 2):

Use dispatch main queue

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.jobImage.image = takenImage
self.takenImage = image
}
```

Comment: so I should replace dispatch main queue with what?

Comment: you should set takenImage value before assigning it to the image view

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `takenImage` is nil while assigning to image view, you need to assign image to `takenImage` before setting to the image view. please update the method like,

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
    print(image)
    self.takenImage = image
    self.jobImage.image = takenImage
    didShowCamera = true
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage`

with

`let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage`

And check whether you have add privacy-photo library access in info.plist.

See detailed at [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1][1]